# Image Zoom not displayed

Tags: javascript, bootstrap-4, zooming

sorry for my English..

I to try this javascript code from [w3schools](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_js_image_zoom).

The difference output between mine and them is that I want my result display on the same window.

How have the code;

Top above;

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.13.0/css/all.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-wvfXpqpZZVQGK6TAh5PVlGOfQNHSoD2xbE+QkPxCAFlNEevoEH3Sl0sibVcOQVnN" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js">  </script>
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto" rel="stylesheet">
```

In Style,

```
* {box-sizing: border-box;}

.grosse-bild {
  position: relative;
}
.img-zoom-lens {
 position: absolute;
 border: 1px solid #d4d4d4;
 /*set the size of the lens:*/
 width: 40px;
 height: 40px;
}
.grosse-bild .kleine-fenster {
  border: 1px solid #d4d4d4;
 /*set the size of the result div:*/
 width: 300px;
 height: 300px;
}
.grosse-bild {  padding: 40px;  background-color: #dedee0;  width: 53.7%;    }

.kleine-fenster{
 width: 50%;

 border: none;
 padding-top: 5px;
 display: block;
 margin-left: auto;
 margin-right: auto;

}
```

The Javascript code,

```
<script>
      // Initiate zoom effect:
    imageZoom("myresult", "myimage");
</script>
```

and

```
function imageZoom(resultID, imgID) {
  var img, lens, result, cx, cy;
  img = document.getElementById(imgID);
  result = document.getElementById(resultID);
    /*create lens:*/
  lens = document.createElement("DIV");
  lens.setAttribute("class", "img-zoom-lens");
     /*insert lens:*/
  img.parentElement.insertBefore(lens, img);
  /*calculate the ratio between result DIV and lens:*/
  cx = result.offsetWidth / lens.offsetWidth;
  cy = result.offsetHeight / lens.offsetHeight;
 /*set background properties for the result DIV:*/
 result.style.backgroundImage = "url('" + img.src + "')";
 result.style.backgroundSize = (img.width * cx) + "px " + (img.height * cy) + "px";
 /*execute a function when someone moves the cursor over the image, or the lens:*/
 lens.addEventListener("mousemove", moveLens);
 img.addEventListener("mousemove", moveLens);
 /*and also for touch screens:*/
 lens.addEventListener("touchmove", moveLens);
 img.addEventListener("touchmove", moveLens);
function moveLens(e) {
  var pos, x, y;
 /*prevent any other actions that may occur when moving over the image:*/
  e.preventDefault();
  /*get the cursor's x and y positions:*/
  pos = getCursorPos(e);
  /*calculate the position of the lens:*/
  x = pos.x - (lens.offsetWidth / 2);
  y = pos.y - (lens.offsetHeight / 2);
  /*prevent the lens from being positioned outside the image:*/
  if (x > img.width - lens.offsetWidth) {x = img.width - lens.offsetWidth;}
  if (x < 0) {x = 0;}
  if (y > img.height - lens.offsetHeight) {y = img.height - lens.offsetHeight;}
  if (y < 0) {y = 0;}
  /*set the position of the lens:*/
  lens.style.left = x + "px";
  lens.style.top = y + "px";
  /*display what the lens "sees":*/
  result.style.backgroundPosition = "-" + (x * cx) + "px -" + (y * cy) + "px";
 }
 function getCursorPos(e) {
  var a, x = 0, y = 0;
  e = e || window.event;
    /*get the x and y positions of the image:*/
  a = img.getBoundingClientRect();
   /*calculate the cursor's x and y coordinates, relative to the image:*/
  x = e.pageX - a.left;
  y = e.pageY - a.top;
    /*consider any page scrolling:*/
  x = x - window.pageXOffset;
  y = y - window.pageYOffset;
  return {x : x, y : y};
 }
}
```

The Html Code,

```
<div class="container">



<div class="grosse-bild">
  <div class="kleine-fenster" id="myresult" > 
    <img src="/kalamulur/Taschen-&-Rucksäcke/Rucksäcke/fenster/photo/113.jpg" width=280 height=280 class="window" id="myimage">
  </div>  
 </div>
</div>
```

[Here](https://jsfiddle.net/ichder/vznqe1h4/3/) to show it..

That problem of this code is that it does nothing...

Can please someone help and say to me where is my mistake?

Comment: First try to make the fiddle work :) maybe some libs are not loaded there. To have just one window i would tack them over each other with css (z-index). then you will get the right coordinates from the base image. Might be also possible that you has to assign the onmouseover event to the lens. cause the original image is then hidden